# Memory management with password retrieval

Tags: c, security, memory-management

Questions:

1. Is this code secure? (I think that it is, but I'm a newbie so I want to be sure.)
2. Is the `get_pass` function correct with passing the arguments to the `free_memory` function?
3. Do I have to delete the pass' buffer with `memset`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void get_pass(char **host, char **user, char **pass);
void free_memory(char *h, char *u, char *p);

int main(){

    char *host, *user, *pass;

    host = (char *) calloc(64, sizeof(char)); /* spazio per max 64 caratteri e inizializzo a 0 (maggior sicurezza) */
    if(!host){
        fprintf(stdout, "\nErrore di allocazione della memoria\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    };

    user = (char *) calloc(64, sizeof(char));
    if(!user){
        fprintf(stdout, "\nErrore di allocazione della memoria\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    };

    pass = (char *) calloc(64, sizeof(char));
    if(!pass){
        fprintf(stdout, "\nErrore di allocazione della memoria\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    };

    /* Immissione di hostname, username e password.
     * Controllo inoltre i 'return code' dei vari fscanf e, se non sono 0, esco.
     * Per evitare buffer overflow imposto limite massimo a 64 caratteri
     */
    fprintf(stdout,"--> Inserisci hostname (max 64 caratteri): ");
    if(fscanf(stdin, "%63s", host) == EOF){
        fprintf(stdout, "\nErrore, impossibile leggere i dati\n");
        free_memory(host,user,pass);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fprintf(stdout,"\n--> Inserisci username (max 64 caratteri): ");
    if(fscanf(stdin, "%63s", user) == EOF){
        fprintf(stdout, "\nErrore, impossibile leggere i dati\n");
        free_memory(host,user,pass);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    };
    fprintf(stdout, "\n--> Inserisci password (max 64 caratteri): ");
    get_pass(&host,&user,&pass);

    /* Stampo a video le informazioni immesse */
    fprintf(stdout, "\n\nHost: %s\nUser: %s\nPass: %s\n\n", host,user,pass);

    free_memory(host,user,pass);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void get_pass(char **host, char **user, char **pass){
    /* Grazie a termios.h posso disabilitare l'echoing del terminale (password nascosta) */
    struct termios term, term_orig;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &term);
        term_orig = term;
        term.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &term);
        /* Leggo la password e controllo il 'return code' di fscanf */
        if(fscanf(stdin, "%63s", *pass) == EOF){
        fprintf(stdout, "\nErrore, impossibile leggere i dati\n");
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &term_orig);
        free_memory(*host, *user, *pass);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    };
        /* Reimposto il terminale allo stato originale */
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &term_orig);
}

void free_memory(char *h, char *u, char *p){
    /* Libero la memoria occupata */
    free(h);
    free(u);
    free(p);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "secure code" and why do you think your code is secure?

Comment: I mean that my code is not vulnerable to buffer overflow...i think that my code is secure because _i think_ that i've done all the checks...but i'm a newbie so i'm not so sure xD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure it's exactly insecure, but I'd consider it excessively verbose and repetitive. Given that your `user`, `host` and `pass` are all small, fixed-size, and allocated for the duration of a single function, dynamic allocation seems to gain little (and cost quite a bit of verbosity) with them. I think I'd write something like this:

```
void getprompt(char *string, size_t max, char const *prompt) { 
    char buffer[16];

    sprintf(buffer, "%%%ds", max-1);
    printf("%s", prompt);
    if (scanf(buffer, string) == EOF) {
        printf("\nErrore, impossibile leggere i dati\n"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }       
}

int main(){
    char host[64], user[64], pass[64];

    getprompt(host, sizeof(host), "--> Inserisci hostname (max 64 caratteri): ");
    getprompt(user, sizeof(user), "\n--> Inserisci username (max 64 caratteri): ");

    printf("\n--> Inserisci password (max 64 caratteri): ");
    get_pass(&host,&user,&pass);

    /* Stampo a video le informazioni immesse */
    printf("\n\nHost: %s\nUser: %s\nPass: %s\n\n", host,user,pass);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

There also seems to be no reason to pass `host` or `user` to `get_pass` -- it doesn't really use them (and logically, shouldn't). I'd probably write it as a wrapper around `getprompt` -- do the `tcsetattr`, call `getprompt`, then undo the `tcsetattr`. Although you have matched the sizes correctly in this case, your `get_pass` has implicit knowledge of the size of `pass`; it works as-is, but is relatively fragile, so in the long term it would be fairly easy for somebody to create a hole by adjusting the size in `get_pass` but not in `main` (or vice versa).

I'd also consider changing `getprompt` to return a `bool` indicating success/failure rather than having it directly exit the program. Along with the suggested change to `getpass`, that would turn your `main` into something like:

```
int main() {
    char host[64], user[64], pass[64];

    if (getprompt(host /* ... */) &&
        getprompt(user /* ... */) &&
        get_pass(pass /* ... */) 
    {
        printf("\n\nHost: %s\nUser: %s\nPass: %s\n\n", host, user, pass);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
};
```

Bottom line: I don't see any obvious security holes in the code as it stands, but it strikes me as excessively verbose and rather fragile. It's unnecessarily difficult to be certain that it's correct now, and likely to get broken in the long term even if it is all correct now.

Comment: wow O.O i don't know what to say :O i still have much to learn and understand...let's start from allocation. You have said that _"Given that your user, host and pass are all small, fixed-size, and allocated for the duration of a single function"_ but  i thought that with calloc i can made dynamic allocation so haven't to know _how long is a string_ . I've used 64 chars because i have to put a "maximum value"...isn't it? Or i can go out of memory...

Comment: @polslinux: `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc` *allow* you to allocate different sizes when needed, but right now your code only allocates one specific size -- and if that's what you're going to do, there's little reason to use them.

Comment: And how can i allocate something dynamically without going out of memory?

Comment: @polslinux: I'm not quite sure exactly what you're asking here...

Comment: nothing...nothing...i have to study more ;(

Comment: I agree that it's an improvement not to use the heap for such small buffers, however note that if you `scanf` with `%64d` into a buffer of 64 `char`s, and you enter a string of length 64, you will end up with a non-zero-terminated string.  (Just tested to confirm.)  This is exactly the opposite of the "secure" coding that was being asked about.  (Generally I would say that use of `scanf` is a big red flag that something bad is likely to be going on, because it's pretty hard to use its clunky interface correctly.)

Comment: @asveikau: Good point. Fixed. But yes, `fgets` is *probably* a better choice.

Comment: I think you also need to zero out that last byte, from your code nobody is ever initializing these things.

Comment: @asveikau: no -- scanf *does* zero-terminate the string.

Answer (score 6):

A few more comments to add to JC's:

- Your use of `fscanf` in `get_pass` prevents the user from using a pass phrase containing spaces.  `fgets` might be a better choice.
- The GNU equivalent of your `get_pass` function (http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/getpass.html) uses `TCSAFLUSH` not `TCSANOW`.  Not sure whether this has any security implications.
- There might be a `getpass()` on your system (OS-X has one)

Comment: Thanks! I've replaced my get_pass with the GNU one! :) ps: i can input password with space..i've tried!

Comment: PS: getpass function is obsolete :( http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpass.3.html

Comment: password with space - using fscanf? I compiled your get_pass and tried it just to be sure yesterday and it does not input spaces (as expected).  "getpass function is obsolete": oops!

Comment: O.o i'm sorry XD i've tried the other code (with getpass)!! You're right it doesn't accept spaces xD

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what has already been said, never typecast the result of malloc/calloc in C. That is dangerous practice. Read [this](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc).